# In Microsoft Azure i have two webapps. Form one Webapp i want to upload image that must be save in the other webapps folder

Tags: c#, azure

The first  web app is the website and the other one is  control panel .So from control panel  admin upload image that must be shown in the website. 
the two webapp are in the  under same resource.

Comment: use N-Tier architecture, upload the image to Azure Blob storage and access from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Look into storing the image as a Blob in [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/). A storage account can be access from multiple applications.

There are several reasons you don't want to (and cannot) store it under the web app. One of them being that ...

> Temporary files are not shared among site instances. Also, you **cannot rely on them staying there**. For instance, if you restart a web app, you'll find that all of these folders get reset to their original state.

Source: [Understanding the Azure App Service file system - Temporary files](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files)